# Auto-updating map service via REST in ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

I have one map service which is updating per day so I need to manually overwrite the service in ArcGIS 10.1 for Server.

In previous versions 10.0 its very easy..just update the .mxd then REST will be auto updated.

Is there any way to auto-update the map service & REST  in ArcGIS 10.1 for Server

I tried the ADMIN API but its not the proper way ... also there are no settings for service definition file in 10.1.

Any help/ideas/workflow?

---

The problem is resolved by adding arcgis account.

Comment: updating how?  If its just a change in records, may not need to  do anything.  Or are you adding/removing/re-ordering the layers in the map service or changing the underlying schema?

Comment: actually its map service created using sql query & the data base is updating daily..I am able to view all records in .mxd but when I check the REST I found that REST is not updating so after overwriting service those updated records I can identify.. I hope it will help us to debug  the issue.. & thanks for reply..

Comment: how did you acheive your requirement. I have a similar requirement and I am also looking for automating the periodically update the data in the service.

Comment: Hi I am using ArcGIS ADMIN API for automatic service publishing + Python module.  Actually its working in 85% cases that's the reason I have not entered here above as answer. Please check details @ http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Scripting_ArcGIS_Server_administration/0154000005p3000000/  Let me know if you have any problem..thanks

Comment: Thank you ..that link is really having loads of nice features.. I am just going over it... Will get back if I have questons.. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of ESRI support I was able to resolve this problem and all my services are live updating the data from the data-base

Following are the steps & I have attached screenshot. I hope it will help for everyone : )

[image: Steps 1]

[image: Steps 2]

Comment: A quick question: how do you update your feature class? Does the service have to be stopped for this?